# Some unit tests not starting in IntelliJ, need help diagnosing issue

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, junit, intellij-idea, spock

I have a huge group of unit tests that I'm running against our software where I work. I'm running them using IntelliJ IDEA.  I'm using Spock and Groovy to make these tests, but they are, in turn, using JUnit.  So anything that applies to JUnit should apply here as well... (in theory)

In order to figure out what coverage is I'm right clicking on the root of the code I want to run and simply selecting "Test in 'example' with Coverage".

IntelliJ then proceeds to try and run the 270 or some odd tests we have in this part of the project.  The problem is that it isn't running a couple of them and I can't figuring out why for the life of me.

I've googled the issue and turned up nothing substantial.  The list of tests in IntelliJ only tells me that these couple of tests didn't start, it doesn't give a reason at all.  I tried checking the logs, but all it says about these particular tests is that it's trying to open them, no comment on how successful they were or were not, and why they aren't working.

If someone could just point me in a useful direction?  I need to expand my test bases coverage and being able to see what code is actually covered is a pretty critical...

Some Clarification:

- The tests can be run on their own, and they do computer coverage for themselves if you do so.  They only can't be run when I run them in a batch.
- I'm pretty sure it's not a display issue because I get several different reports telling me that the tests were not run.  So, more than just the frozen yellow spinner it also warns me with a red "attention" bubble that the tests did not run.

Comment: Try to dig deeper and provide more detailed information. For example, do the problematic tests get run when you run all tests, without computing coverage? Can you run them in isolation? Can you compute coverage for them in isolation? Have you double-checked that this isn't just a display issue (and how did you do that)? Etc.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser -- There, I tried to answer the questions you posed.  As I've mentioned, I'm a little stumped on even where to begin.  If you have further questions, feel free to ask them.

Comment: One more thing I'd check is if the problem is specific to Spock tests (rather than plain JUnit tests). In any case, I'm afraid I don't know the answer. You might want to take this to the IntelliJ forums.

Comment: Firstly, restarting, invalidate caches and rebuild might always help. Now, if you right-click at the top of the test-source root in the module (the green folder) and select `Create 'All Tests'`, can you try running with *Search for tests:* `Across module dependencies` and see if it hits them all? The tests in question do have at least one `@Test` (that is not `@Ignored`), right?

Comment: Spock tests don't use `@Test`.